# Hiding user login on single-user sites

Tags: authentication, hidden

If I'm building a simple page to which one person (or a small number of people) will have admin access, how do I (ideally language-agnostically, but in Ruby if relevant) conceal the log-in link from most users, but reveal it to those who should have access?

I feel like this is something people must do all the time, and the answer is presumably all over Google, but I'm not quite sure what question I'm asking. I don't know what info I'd have to condition on (IP? What if admins want to log in from a different Wifi network?).

Is the normal approach to just not have a link, and use cURL or similar tools to log in? (which seems unwieldy)

Comment: In your server-side code you can conditionally show or not show any page element based on any condition you want.  What is the condition you're looking to check?  What piece of information do you have in any given page request that you will use to determine whether or not you should show the login prompt?  (Note also, that same condition should be used in processing the login as well.  Never assume that just because you don't show a UI element to a user that they can't possibly make a request based on it.)

Comment: It's mainly for UX rather than security - I don't want people to see a login link they can't use. Just realised the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just realised at least one way of doing this is to have a page that I need to direct link to as the login page, so no-one sees a login link they can't use.

Feels obvious in retrospect :\